# How do I access the Oxford Latin Dictionary online?

Tags: dictionary, reference-request

I'm using a university account to sign into [Oxford Scholarly Editions Online](http://www.oxfordscholarlyeditions.com/) (OSEO).

1. To what 'widget' does [the official webpage](http://www.oxfordscholarlyeditions.com/page/the-oxford-latin-dictionary) refer? Is it online? Must it be downloaded?

> A **widget** enabling users to look up words in the *Oxford Latin Dictionary*, ed. P. G. W. Glare (2nd edn, 2012), is included for all users of the Latin content on *Oxford Scholarly Editions Online*.

2. I [searched for it on OSEO](http://www.oxfordscholarlyeditions.com/search?q=The+Oxford+Latin+Dictionary&isNewSearch=true&onlyPreferredWorks=true&searchBtn=Search), but see no result?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you must have an institutional subscription to **the Latin content** on Oxford Scholarly Editions Online.

You don’t need to download anything.

“Select any word in a Latin text and a pop-up menu will appear.”

Answer (score 2):

Or just go here for a pdf:

https://archive.org/details/aa.-vv.-oxford-latin-dictionary-1968/page/1293/mode/2up

extra characters here.

Comment: Do you know the copyright status of this? Last time this was posted here, it was eventually deleted for copyright violation.